# ticket booking engine rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Im trying o set up an rails application that handles ticket booking system for e venue.
Does anybody have any suggestions about architecture, gems or general approach yhat could help? Would be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  You might want to start with the getting started guide, and that might give you some more specific questions - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you already know RoR yet? If not, try this tutorial [Rails turotial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), then you can build your application, because only you know what you need, so keep learning and building and if you have trouble or problem then go to stackoverflow and ask, so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I only found [this one](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb) that integrates with the Zendesk site through its API